# How does a symbol table connect a symbol with its definition?

Tags: c++

I know that it really is implementation-defined, but almost always are some common features/approaches. So how does a symbol table usually connect a symbol with its definition when and when not the definition is present in the current translation unit?

Comment: They have an index(es) mapping symbol names to offsets.

Comment: @jotik so does the definition have certain address which will determine the offset from a symbol? :/ That was not as detailed as I was hoping for :(

Comment: Go and read a compiler text book this is too broad for SO.

Comment: @RichardCritten well, wouldn't some clever pal be able to come up with a quite clear but also detailed enough definite "overall" answer to the common approach? I cannot see how this is too broad since a definite answer is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this can be achieved in 3 ways.

1. If the symbol is local, the compiler will resolve references and there is no more to do.
2. If the symbol is global and position dependent then symbols will be resolved at link edit time (e.g., a .a or .lib library).
3. If the symbol is global and position dependent then the symbols are resolved again by the link editor at link time. Rather than being resolved directly, symbols are referenced by an offset table. Then at runtime, the link loader will resolve the offsets (e.g., a .so or .dll library).

See 'Linkers & Loaders' by Levine if you like book references. Online, Oracle's [Linker and Libraries Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-1984/index.html) is the best that I've read.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But so let's say you have an initialized variable `int num = 2;`, how would that look in a symbol table? Are symbols connected to the address of definitions or?

Comment: Both with variables and functions. I know that the compiler leaves a "note" when the definition is not present in the source file, but what about when the definition is present?